# Grouped pivot_longer dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

This is an example dataframe. My real dataframe is larger. I highly prefer a tidyverse solution.

```
#my data
age <- c(18,18,19)
A1 <- c(3,5,3)
A2 <- c(4,4,3)
B1 <- c(1,5,2)
B2 <- c(2,2,5)
df <- data.frame(age, A1, A2, B1, B2)
```

I want my data to look like this:

```
#what i want
new_age <- c(18,18,18,18,19,19)
A <- c(3,5,4,4,3,3)
B <- c(1,5,2,2,2,5)
new_df <- data.frame(new_age, A, B)
```

I want to pivot longer and stack columns A1:A2 into column A, and B1:B2 into B. I also want to have the responses to match the correct age. For example, the 19 year old person in this example has only responded with 3's in columns A1:A2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
tidyr::pivot_longer(df, cols = -age, names_to = c(".value",'groupid'), 
                    #1+ non digits followed by 1+ digits
                    names_pattern = "(\\D+)(\\d+)")
# A tibble: 6 x 4
    age groupid   A     B
  <dbl> <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
1    18 1         3     1
2    18 2         4     2
3    18 1         5     5
4    18 2         4     2
5    19 1         3     2
6    19 2         3     5
```

Comment: 1) Do you have any recommendations on where I can learn more about names_pattern input? I am not comfortable with pivot_longer yet.

2) Can you use starts_with in names_pattern?

edit: I'm going to look into extract() and pivot_longer_spec()
https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pivot_longer.html

Comment: See [here](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/articles/pivot.html#many-variables-in-column-names) for `tidyr` and for `names_pattern` you need to be familiar with regular expressions which you can find in [this](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/articles/regular-expressions.html#look-arounds) `stringr` tutorial. regarding 2: No we can't use `start_with` as we telling `pivot_longer` how to create the new groups "columns"

Answer (score 2):

in Base R you will use `reshape` then select the columns you want. You can change the row names also

```
reshape(df,2:ncol(df),dir = "long",sep="")[,-c(2,5)] # 
    age A B
1.1  18 3 1
2.1  18 5 5
3.1  19 3 2
1.2  18 4 2
2.2  18 4 2
3.2  19 3 5
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have a larger dataframe, maybe a solution with `data.table` will be faster. Here, you can use `melt` function from `data.table` package as follow:

```r
library(data.table)
colA = grep("A",colnames(df),value = TRUE)
colB = grep("B",colnames(df),value = TRUE)
setDT(df)

df <- melt(df, measure = list(colA,colB), value.name = c("A","B"))
df[,variable := NULL]
dt <- dt[order(age)]

   age A B
1:  18 3 1
2:  18 5 5
3:  18 4 2
4:  18 4 2
5:  19 3 2
6:  19 3 5
```

Does it answer your question ?

**EDIT: Using patterns - suggestion from @Wimpel**

As @Wimpel suggested it in comments, you can get the same result using patterns:

```r
melt( setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns( A="^A[0-9]", B="^B[0-9]") )[, variable:=NULL][]

   age A B
1:  18 3 1
2:  18 5 5
3:  19 3 2
4:  18 4 2
5:  18 4 2
6:  19 3 5
```

Comment: or use `patterns` like: `melt( setDT(df), measure.vars = patterns( A="^A[0-9]", B="^B[0-9]") )[, variable:=NULL][]`

Comment: Nice ! Thank you for the suggestion, I will add it to my answer. I was not sure how to combine multiple commands into a single line.